# Spotify app - start playback of local file

Tags: javascript, spotify

I'd like to know how to start playback of local file if making a spotify app (I'm aware Spotify stopped accepting new apps until new APIs come, I want to know anyway).

In the "Spotify Apps API tutorials" the following javascript can be used to create a button which can start playback of a spotify song:

```
require(['$api/models', '$views/image#Image'], function(models, Image) {

    // Play a single track
    var track = models.Track.fromURI('spotify:track:7B1Dl3tXqySkB8OPEwVvSu');
    var image = Image.forTrack(track, {player: true});

    // Pass the player HTML code to the #single-track-player div
    document.getElementById('single-track-player')
        .appendChild(image.node);
});
```

How do I make my spotify app start playing a local mp3?

Comment: Until new APIs come? I thought they didn't say anything about plans on accepting new app submissions again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure from playing with it that you have to have the local file in your "Local Files" listing before you'll be able to play it.

After that you'll just use the spotify:local:... syntax.  I didn't find any good documentation of it.  I've tried taking uri's retrieved by right-clicking a song and choosing "Copy Spotify URI" and modifying them, then pasting it in the search bar.  It seems to not be very flexible.

I think you'll only be able to do this if you can get the user to drag/drop a track in for you.  Not sure without experimenting whether their Library would include their local tracks or not.